# OR vs AND in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql and I can query in both ways (or / and)
That means I can write query as:
select * from x where () or () or () . . .. ;
or I can write as:
select * from x where () and () and () . . .. ;

Which is preferable? Is there any performance issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about performance and what's "preferable", you need to use `or`, `and` depending on what you want from your query. This is basic [boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic) using truth tables. `select * from x where () or () or ()` will be very different from `select * from x where () and () and ()`.

Comment: Not exactly always. As we know from logic, both can be same if the problem is in a specific way. But it's too hard to find such problems. Anyway, I got my answer.

Comment: @Mazhar: true, there are cases when using `ANDs` and `ORs` will produce the same result, but you're more likely to find such examples in theory than in practise.

Comment: I guess so. But I fall with a problem like that in practical. That why I thought if there is anything I need to know about performance.

Comment: @Mazhar: modern SQL engines will probably do some internal refactoring to your query for optimization, so some `AND` might get turned into a combination of `ORs` and vice versa, so from a performance standpoint, there's nothing to worry about. A smart SQL engine will probably do a better job than you would in this case.

Answer (score 2):

How could this be a performance thing - as both queries work differently?

If you have `where () or () or ()`; results are returned if ANY of the conditions is met

And if you have `where () and () and ()`; results are returned only if ALL of the conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample predicates are not semantically equivalent so I wonder if you've oversimplified or forgotten to mention negation? e.g. something more like this:

```
 WHERE (NOT col1 = 'T') OR (NOT col2 = 'T') OR (NOT col3 = 'T');
```

is the same as

```
 WHERE NOT (col1 = 'T' AND col2 = 'T' AND col3 = 'T');
```

If so, I think that what @darioo said in comments is the answer i.e. that the engine will interpret the correct boolean logic as it sees fit and probably isn't worth worrying about. Your job is to ensure that your candidate constructs that you will be performance testing are indeed semantically equivalent :)